# Adding integers and displaying in a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, uilabel, counter

I am working on a scoreboard of sorts.  The player can adjust three different values (gear, level, and bonuses) that when added should provide a total strength.  Each of these values is currently being output as an integer and a UILabel displays its' respective integer.  I cannot figure out how to add all three integers and then display them on a UILabel.  I am currently developing for iOS 7 but I don't imagine this to be terribly different for current supported OS's.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int levelCount;
int gearCount;
int oneShotCount;
int totalScoreCount;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalScore;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *playerName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *levelNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *gearNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *oneShotNumber;
- (IBAction)levelUpButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)levelDownButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)gearUpButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)gearDownButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)oneShotUpButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)oneShotDownButton:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int ans = levelCount + gearCount + oneShotCount;
    self.levelNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ans];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)levelUpButton:(id)sender {
    levelCount = levelCount + 1;
    self.levelNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", levelCount];


}

- (IBAction)levelDownButton:(id)sender {
    levelCount = levelCount - 1;
    self.levelNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", levelCount];

}


- (IBAction)gearUpButton:(id)sender {
    gearCount = gearCount + 1;
    self.gearNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gearCount];
}

- (IBAction)gearDownButton:(id)sender {
    gearCount = gearCount - 1;
    self.gearNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gearCount];
}


- (IBAction)oneShotUpButton:(id)sender {
    oneShotCount = oneShotCount + 1;
    self.oneShotNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", oneShotCount];
}

- (IBAction)oneShotDownButton:(id)sender {
    oneShotCount = oneShotCount - 1;
    self.oneShotNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", oneShotCount];
}



@end
```

Comment: Side note - why did you declare global variables for `levelCount`, `gearCount`, etc. in the .h file? Why aren't these private ivars instead of globals?

Comment: Honestly, because I have no idea what I'm doing.  I don't expect you to teach me everything but if you're willing I wouldn't mind knowing the difference.  I've been trying to learn objective C but books and whatnot are outdated.

Comment: Start with a good book or tutorial on the Objective-C programming language. The book by Stephen G. Kochan is very good. Writing apps requires knowledge of the language first.

Comment: Very good.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some sort of `updateScore` method that is called anytime one of the other values change.

```
- (void)updateScore {
    totalScoreCount = ... // calculate score from levelCount, gearCount, and oneShotCount

    self.totalScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalScoreCount];
}
```

Then in each of your `...UpButton:` and `...DownButton:` methods you call:

```
[self updateScore];
```

Be sure to call this after updating the other value first. Example:

```
- (IBAction)levelUpButton:(id)sender {
    levelCount = levelCount + 1;
    self.levelNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", levelCount];
    [self updateScore];
}
```